# Why doesn't fprintf work after fscanf?

Tags: scanf, printf

I want to open a file for both writing and reading, but after I read from it, I can't write to it:

```
f_prefs = fopen(prefs_path, "r+");
while (fscanf(f_prefs, "%[^\n]\n", line) == 1)
{
    ... do some stuff ...
    fprintf(f_prefs, "test"); // doesn't work
    ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has to be a file positioning operation between each switch in direction - from read to write or from write to read.  In case of doubt, use `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);`, which seeks zero bytes from the current position.  Note that you would need two `fseek()` operations in the loop!

#### C99 §7.19.5.3 The fopen() function

> When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the
>   above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the
>   associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an
>   intervening call to the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek,
>   fsetpos, or rewind), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an
>   intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-
>   file.